# Can FPDF support rich text formating

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf

i have a database of chemicals, I used

nicEdit-latest.js

to enable rich text formatting, so that i can now save chemical names like CO2  to CO<sub>2</sub>. My problem is that when i print the report in PDF using 'FPDF' class, it prints out the tag CO<sub>2</sub> .  I have looked at the class 'subwrite()' but i don't seem to get the logic right.

Has any one had a similar problem and found a solution or can you help.

Comment: Is there a way , i can position the output using $pdf->writehtml

Comment: I used WriteHtmlCell  and it works  .  So now am alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used WriteHtmlCell and it works . So now am alright